# How can I prove that the following function is a homeomorphism? $f_T:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, spheres

I need to prove the following $\pi_1\left(f_T(\mathbb{S}^2), f_T(\mathbf{x}_0)\right)\simeq \pi_1\left(\mathbb{S}^2, \mathbf{x}_0\right)$.

My idea is to prove that the function $f_T$ is an homeomorphism, i need prove $f_T$
is continuous and has an inverse.

Let the matrix $T$  $\in \mathbb{GL}_3(\mathbb{C})\cap\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ such that $T\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{S}^2$ for every $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{S}^2$.
Then consider the function $f_T:\mathbb{S}^2 \to \mathbb{S}^2, y\to Ty$

Comment: Why not compose with your self-map $f_T$? In other words, given a loop $\gamma: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^2$, map the homotopy class: $[\gamma] \mapsto [f_T \circ \gamma]$. You have to check that this map (1) is well-defined, (2) sends basepoint to basepoint, and (3) is invertible. Can you write down the inverse map?